# Why is ActiveStorage with S3 raising InvalidBucketName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I've just added ActiveStorage to a Rails app using S3. My first use of AS on a staging env raises

```
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidBucketName: The specified bucket is not valid.
```

The bucket already exists on S3 and ActiveStorage has the correct bucket name, region, etc. defined in `storage.yml`.

ActiveStorage has been given AWS IAM credentials that have full S3 access.

The bucket has been configured for CORS

```
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
```

Why am I getting an `InvalidBucketName` error? What other things should I look at?

```
#storage.yml
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') %>
  region: us-east-1
  bucket: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_S3_BUCKET') %>
```

Comment: Can you check if the user who owns the access key has permission ?

Comment: Thanks @KedarnagMukanahallipatna , that user has full S3 get, put, delete, list etc permissions

Comment: Can you try uploading a file into the bucket using the `CLI` and see if you get the same error ?

Comment: `aws s3 cp my-file.jpg s3://my-bucket` successfully uploads the file, which is now accessible in the S3 panel

Comment: Using the same credentials, of course

Comment: Can you share `storage.yml` ?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna added!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180213/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-andy-harvey).

Comment: @AndyHarvey I'm experiencing the same issue and tried the same sanity checks. Did you figure out what the cause of yours was?

Comment: @tomjohn sorry I don’t recall precisely what the issue was. If I remember, it may have been something to do with conflicting AWS SDK gems. I’ll take a look back at this over the coming days and see whether something jogs my memory!

Comment: @AndyHarvey That would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: @AndyHarvey I found my issue. I forgot to add embedded ruby syntax around my `ENV.fetch` call for the bucket name in storage.yml ... smh